# Changes to be made for JDBC datasource while migrating from tomcat 7 to weblogic 11g

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, jsf-1.2, weblogic11g, trinidad

I have ported my JSF application from **Apache Tomcat 7.0.14** to **Weblogic 11g**.I am using `JSF 1.2` and `Apache Trinidad 1.2.14`.

As expected i am having problems with my `JNDI` look up in the Weblogic 11g.

I have seen how to configure a `JDBC` data source in weblogic from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jdbc/jdbc_datasources/CreateDataSources.html).

My requirement is i don't want to make **System wide JDBC data source**.I want it to be application specific.

I already have a `context.xml` for my application.How i have to change it for weblogic to understand?

or do i have to have another file all together for weblogic to understand?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13737/config.htm) explains how to configure system vs. application specific JDBC modules. It even contains naming constraints for application JDBC modules. You need to create a xml file with a specific name (ending with -jdbc.xml) and embed it into your application descriptor.